# How to run run C++ apps in android?

Tags: c++, android, cygwin, android-ndk

How to run c++ applications in android using cygwin. Any tutorial in this regard is appreciated..

Comment: In Android using Cygwin? Huh..?

Answer (score 17):

You cannot directly run C++ applications in Android.
Android can run only applications written using the Android SDK, but yes you can re-use your native(C/C++) libraries for Android.

You will have to recompile all the native libraries specifically for Android. And you do need the source code for all 3rd party native libs you plan to use simply because Usually when we compile and link these libraries outside Android they are linked to glibc but unfortunately Android doesn't use glibc due to liscence and performance issues. Android uses a watered down version of glibc called libc. It has matching symbol names to glibc for most of the usual functionalities. But as far as i know the libc doesn't have some functionality related to Strings and it definitely doesnt have some posix support. If your native libraries are using any of the deprecated functionality you will have to find workaround for those by using alternative functionality supported by libc and coding your libs accordingly.

Also, you will have to use the [***NDK***](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/) to interface Java(Android app/fwk) to native world(C++). And then write a Android application on top of that.

Though this sounds pretty simple in my experience compiling native libraries on Android(Android porting) has traditionally been very time consuming with no guarantee of sucesses.

Comment: In fact, instead of building `lib` and consuming it with Java, you can compile `executable` using NDK c++ environment. And it will run on Android like any other Linux executables.

Answer (score 0):

You will want the Java Native Interface, or "JNI".

See: "[Java Native Interface Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)" "[Android JNI Tips](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/jni-tips.html)" and links therein. It is some work to get this going and to get used to how it goes. I managed it from the references given here with `C` and it will work out after some time and faith without further help if you follow all the steps.